# Change time format to 24hr (military time) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5, global-asax, time-format

My ASP.NET MVC 5 application currently displays times in 12 hour format. How can I change this to display times in 24 hour format?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083986/how-do-i-convert-the-time-to-military-time), but is there anything I can do on an application level to apply this? I mean maybe add something in global.asax or web.config which will change the time format throughout the application?

Comment: You mean like `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Can you show the code where actually the 12 hour format is produced? I mean, where the time is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this way, add `Application_BeginRequest` method in Global.asax.cs:

```
// using System.Globalization;
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "MM dd yyyy";
    // there are a lot of other pattern properties in ci.DateTimeFormat you can set 
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
}
```

Then you invoke `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` and will get `02 17 2016`(for Feb 17, 2016)